What’s the intended way to trigger a spice bloom?
In 1992’s Dune II: The Building of a Dynasty (AKA Dune: The Battle for Arrakis), the main goal is harvesting one of the two resources that can be found on the planet: the spice melange.
The spice appears as speckled orange tiles (of two levels of concentration) in the otherwise sandy desert.  Harvesters can gather spice from these directly.  But there’s also the occasional lump in the sand.  When a unit walks or drives over one of these lumps, it locates a “spice bloom”, which releases a large number of spice tiles in an explosion that kills the unit.
It’s perfectly reasonable that a poorly directed unit can be lost by accidentally stepping on the wrong tile.  But how am I supposed to trigger a spice bloom on purpose?
When I need more spice, I usually resort to triggering one of these blooms by sacrificing a single soldier (which has already suffered considerable damage).  Or, if I’ve only got one harvester (that’s relatively empty), sending it to its doom.  (Apparently your last harvester gets redeployed for free — at least in the early levels.)  But sacrificing a unit each time seems to be too wasteful to be the intended method; surely there must be another way.
Is there a way to trigger a spice bloom without losing a unit?

Related: Detonating a spice bloom in the middle of a spice field. Gain or Loss?

You should be able to trigger these spice blooms by shooting at them with an explicit Attack command, although you might need a minimum range to not get caught in the bloom (I wouldn't use an infantry squad). I'm not sure if there's an amount of damage you need to do or if it just activates on any shot.
